# jquery nextAll element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this is my html

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" data-site="1">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="text" data-site="2">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="text" data-site="3">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="text" data-site="5">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="text" data-site="6">
</fieldset>
```

i have to select next element after **data-site="3"**
i try with

```
$('input[data-site=3]').closest('fieldset').nextAll().find('input[data-site]');
```

but not works. I should receive input[data-site=5] ed input[data-site=6]

any idea?

Comment: since you have updated the question using `.closest()` it should be fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tHW9G/1/

Comment: just make sure your script is executed after the target elements are loaded in the dom

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EMtQ8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of **[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)**:

> Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

In your case, `input` is not the sibling of each other. So you need to do:

```
$('input[data-site=3]').parent().nextAll().find('input[data-site]');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdh2Z/)**

Comment: @FelixKling current version there is nothing wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tHW9G/1/ - but original version didn't had the parent lookup